# alt text is displayed when linking image

Tags: markdown, pandoc

The first code snippet links to an image using the URL. When I use Pandoc to convert this to a docx file the image is shown and "alt text1" is not displayed unless the image cannot be displayed. This is the behavior that I expected from the documentation.

```
![alt text1](http://daringfireball.net/graphics/logos/ "title text")
```

However, in the second snippet I link directly to the image on my computer. Then when I use Pandoc to convert and view the docx file both the image and "alt text2" is displayed.

```
![alt text2](img/example.png "title text")
```

My workaround is to simply leave "alt text2" blank, but I was curious why this was happening?

Comment: How are you converting your Markdown to docx? Are you using Pandoc or some other tool? Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: does the second image form a paragraph on its own, while the first one is part of some more text without a newline separating them? if so, see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-implicit_figures